# Is it possible to setText of TextView in MainActivity.java using string.xml?

Tags: java, android, xml

In my code I have the xml string that I would like to replace in the java file with another string from the string.xml, if the TextView is clicked. Can I input a string from the string.xml file into the mainactity.java file?

```
//activity_main.xml
android:id="@+id/description"
android:text="description of activity"

//MainActivity.java
TextView moreInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
    moreInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            moreInfo.setText(@string/description_activity_main);)
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You're just doing it wrong. Here's what you should do:

```
moreInfo.setText(getString(R.string.description_activity_main));
```

Answer (score 0):

XML file saved at res/values/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="hello">Hello!</string>
</resources>
```

This application code retrieves a string:

```
String string = getString(R.string.hello);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your string from `string.xml` by using `getResources()` which can be used after importing `R` file as,

```
import com.example.R; // com.example should be replaced your package path
```

Then change as the following,

```
moreInfo.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.description_activity_main));
```

Answer (score 0):

use `getString()` function 

`getString(R.string.sting_name)`